# Is this Lie algebra Noetherian (satisfy the maximal condition for ideals)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ have the basis $x$, $(y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $[x,y_n]=y_{n+1}$ and $[y_n,y_m]=0$.

The ideals are $0$, the ideal $I_n$ with basis $(y_k:k\ge n)$, and all subspaces containing the derived subalgebra $I_1$.

> Is this Lie algebra Noetherian (satisfy the maximal condition for ideals)?

> Could I obtain a semi-prime ideal such that $r(P) \not = P$?

A Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ satisfy the maximal condition for ideals, if for each , ascending chain $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2} \subseteq \ldots $ an index $m$ exists such that $H_{i}=H_{k}$ if $m<i$, $m<k .$

We say in short: $ \mathfrak{g} \in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$ or $\mathfrak{g}$ is Noetherian Lie algebra.

Comment: If your second paragraph is correct, it follow that all ideals $\neq 0$ have finite codimension, which answers your first question with "yes", and it follows that the answer to the second question is "no". Actually, since $[I_n, I_n]=0$, it follows from your second paragraph that the only semi-prime ideal is the entire Lie algebra.

Comment: what do you mean? Does the definition of Noetherian in the second paragraph is incorrect?

Comment: By "second paragraph" I mean the sentence "The ideal are $0$, [...] subalgebra $I_1$." What I mean is that I have not checked the statements in that sentence, but if they are correct, they easily answer your questions.

Comment: I understand your idea. Thanks. I try to find ideals in non-Noetherian Lie algebra because most of Lie algebras are Noetherian.

Answer (score 2):

There are many more ideals than you're claiming, still it's noetherian.

Indeed, let $V$ be the hyperplane with basis $(y_n)$, and $T$ the operator $y_n\mapsto y_{n+1}$, and $K$ the ground field. Then a subspace of $V$ is an ideal iff it is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Make $V$ a $K[x]$-module with $x$ acting as $T$. Then $V$ is generated by $y_0$ and hence, being infinite-dimensional over $K$, is a free $K[x]$-module of rank 1. Hence it's a noetherian module: precisely its submodules are $\{0\}$ and for each element of the form $y=y_n+\sum_{i=n+1}^Na_jy_j$, the submodule generated by $y$ (this just reflects that $K[x]$ is a PID and that every nonzero ideal is generated by a unique monic polynomial). Only for $y=y_n$ this corresponds to one of the ideals you list. For instance, the ideal generated by $y_0-y_1$ contains no $y_n$.

The remaining ideals, i.e., those not contained in $V$, contain $y_1$  and hence have codimension $\le 2$. Hence, every nonzero ideal has finite codimension, so $\mathfrak{g}$ is noetherian.